# Добавление множества CSS-файлов в шаблон Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

Создаю шаблон в друпале по своей верстке. В файле test.info (конфигурация моего шаблона)  прописываю путь к css файлам. `stylesheets[all][] = style.css` - пример подключения стиля, но у меня их много (100+), и писать 100 команд не очень практично. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить все стили.

Answer (score 2):

Можно в template.php использовать функцию [drupal_add_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7.x).

Как пример:

```
function test_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    foreach (glob(path_to_theme() . "/css/*.css") as $css) {
        drupal_add_css($css);
    }
}
```

Но вобще 100+ css-файлов - это много, на мой взгляд. Лучше их объединить.